# Remove element from an array without rearrange

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to remove a specific element from an array.i used splice method for that.but the problem is i don't want my array be rearranged after that.
in other words if we have

```
 var ar:Array = [0,1,5,3];

 ar.splice(2,1);

 trace(ar[2]);
```

and ar[2] is 3 now.

but i want to be undefined.

how can i do that?

Comment: You mean you would rather have `undefined` in place of a removed element than have all the elements moved down to the front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign `undefined` to the index you want to remove:

```
ar[2] = undefined;
```

Comment: Though I am doubtful that this is actually what you want to do - if you update your question to include the reason that you want to do this, I will be able to give a far more appropriate answer.